# Trying to retrieve current user data in profile in flutter application, but fetching problem

Tags: java, php, mysql, flutter, kotlin

can anyone please help me, i want to retrieve current user data with shared preferences in flutter application, after login in successfully i have stored my session id in shared preferences,

then i want to retrieve current user data from api , the api scripts is written in php script,

i cannot figure it out that what is happening, but data is not retrieving , only showing the session id as i mentioned it in text format, so please help me with it

with this code i stored session id

```
if (success) {
        // Login successful
        // Save idNo to session
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        await prefs.setString('idNo', idNo);

        // Navigate to the next screen or perform desired actions
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()),
        );
      }
```

```
i am using this in api


<?php
// Establish database connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test_user";
$password = "test123456";
$dbname = "test_user";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Get input from the Flutter app
$idNo = $_POST['session_id']; // Update the key to match the Flutter code

// Prepare and execute the SQL query
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM retailer_details WHERE retailer_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $idNo);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // User data found
    $userData = $result->fetch_assoc();

    // Send response back to the Flutter app
    $response = array("success" => true, "message" => "User data retrieved", "data" => $userData);
} else {
    // User data not found
    $response = array("success" => false, "message" => "User data not found");
}

// Send response back to the Flutter app
echo json_encode($response);

// Close database connection
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

and the profile.dart code is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  String sessionId = '';
  Map<String, dynamic>? userData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchSessionId().then((_) {
      fetchUserData();
    });
  }

  Future<void> fetchSessionId() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? idNo = prefs.getString('idNo');
    if (idNo != null) {
      setState(() {
        sessionId = idNo;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchUserData() async {
    try {
      if (sessionId.isEmpty) {
        throw Exception('Session ID not available');
      }
      Map<String, dynamic> data = await getUserData(sessionId);
      setState(() {
        userData = data;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to fetch user data: $e');
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content: Text('Failed to fetch user data: $e'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                child: Text('OK'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserData(String sessionId) async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://hidden_domain.com/api/user_data.php');
    var response = await http.post(
      url,
      body: {
        'session_id': sessionId,
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (data['success']) {
        return data['data'][0] as Map<String, dynamic>;
      } else {
        throw Exception(data['message']);
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch user data');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Session ID: $sessionId'),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            if (userData != null) ...[
              Text('Name: ${userData!['retailer_id']}'),
              Text('Email: ${userData!['retailer_name']}'),
              // Display other user data fields as needed
            ] else ...[
              Text('Fetching user data...'),
            ],
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```